# Cannot access recordIssues in Jenkins Pipeline using Warnings Next Generation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a simple Jenkinsfile with a recordIssues step. The relevant code looks like this:

```
   step([
        $class: 'recordIssues',
        aggregatingResults: true,
        enabledForFailure: true,
        tools: [pyLint()]
    ])
```

I have installed the latest version of the Warnings Next Generation plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng) but I run into the following issue:

```
[Pipeline] step
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep is named recordIssues
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.resolveClass(DescribableModel.java:478)
```

Is it somehow possible to check that the extension is installed correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my working version for a Python project CI configuration in Jenkins to use JUnit, PEP8, Pylint and Coverage reports:

```
    ...

    stage('Test: Run') {
        steps {
            // Run my project tests.
            sh 'coverage run manage.py tests'

            // Dump coverage metrics to XML.
            sh 'coverage xml'

            // Run Pylint.
            sh 'pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc my_project > reports/pylint.report'

            // Run Pycodestyle (PEP8 checks).
            sh 'pycodestyle my_project > reports/pep8.report'
        }
        post {
            always{
                // Generate JUnit, PEP8, Pylint and Coverage reports.
                junit 'reports/*junit.xml'
                recordIssues(
                    tool: pep8(pattern: 'reports/pep8.report'),
                    unstableTotalAll: 200,
                    failedTotalAll: 220
                )
                recordIssues(
                    tool: pyLint(pattern: 'reports/pylint.report'),
                    unstableTotalAll: 20,
                    failedTotalAll: 30
                )
                cobertura coberturaReportFile: 'reports/coverage.xml'
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

It works with [Cobertura plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cobertura), [JUnit plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/junit) and [Warnings Next Generation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng). Python packages I used are the traditional [coverage](https://pypi.org/project/coverage/) and [pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) and for PEP8 I used [pycodestyle](https://pypi.org/project/pycodestyle/).

Hope this helps somebody else, as finding good examples of this `Jenkinsfile` stuff is not easy.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record: 
Jenkins v2.204.2
Jenkins Warnings Next Generation Plugin v8.0.0

```
  stage('Static Analysis') {
    steps {
        recordIssues(
            tool: pyLint(pattern: '**/pylint.out'),
            unstableTotalAll: 100,
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (Jenkins ver. 2.164.1):

```
    stage('Static Analysis') {

        recordIssues(
            tool: pyLint(pattern: '**/pylint.out'),
            unstableTotalAll: '100',
       )

        recordIssues(
            tool: pep8(pattern: '**/pep8.out'),
            unstableTotalAll: '100',
       )
    }
```